# Quantile Regression Coefficients When Data has a Missing Value

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, regression

Consider a scenario in executing quantile regression using $p=0.5$ (the quantile) using the formula $Y \sim 1 + X$ with a dataframe containing two columns.  One column contains values for $Y$ and the other column contains values for $X$.  However, one of the values for $Y$ is missing.

Is it possible to determine $\hat{\beta}_0$ if we don't know the missing value?  Likewise, is it possible to determine $\hat{\beta}_1$ if we don't know the missing value?  Is it possible to determine both of these coefficients, one of them, or neither at all?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to ensure clarity, $Y \sim 1 + X$ just refers to a quantile regression model fit with an intercept and a slope on $X$.  The question I'm curious about is theoretical in nature about whether it is possible to find the values of the two coefficients.  I'm not necessarily curious about how to accommodate a missing value.